# gnome-screenshot area clipboard not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: clipboard, screenshot

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10.1. Being used to the Ctrl-Shift-PrtScr, I really miss that. For some reason, it just doesn't copy the screenshot to clipboard.

When I manually execute `gnome-screenshot --area --clipboard`, the same thing happens. It gives me a crosshair to select an area, makes a shutter sound and the newly made screenshot is nowhere to be seen. Not even in the Pictures folder.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Are you using Wayland or X.Org? You can select it in the login screen settings. There are issues like that on Wayland.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine I was using Wayland. Moving to X solved the issue, thanks. Feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use X.Org. You can select in in the login screen settings.

Ubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland display manager by default instead of X.Org. Not all applications support Wayland. Issues can be seen especially with screen sharing/recording software and like.